# Setting up a status code for a Response Entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, response, http-status-codes

I have the following response:

```
noResultsResponse.setMessage("No available models");
return ResponseEntity.status(404).body(noResultsResponse);
```

This works and returns `404` with the correct message.

But when I try to use a different status code, for an example `return ResponseEntity.status(1001).body(noResultsResponse);`, it returns a `500` error code with the correct message.

Is there no way of setting up 4 digit status codes without actually making a status field in the response and return it as a `200` code?

Comment: its returns 500 error code because 1001 its not a valid http status code.

Answer (score 0):

Status codes are issued by a server in response to a client's request made to the server. The first digit of the status-code defines the class of response.

Refer to this for the valid status codes [httpstatuses.com](https://httpstatuses.com/)

Best way to set and return response from server:

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
```